# I May Drop My Masters In 3rd Year, Would This Be Seen As A Red Flag Trying To Career Switch Into Software Development?

Tags: software-industry, career-switch, student

I started my masters in environmental economics in 2018. I was a top student, volunteered on the departmental graduate student group, did professional development, and contributed to the department's administration team. I even got accepted into a PhD program this September. In the following paragraphs, I will provide some context for how I got to this position, and summarize at the end with my question.

When it came time to choose a supervisor after my first year, I chose someone who was (1) not an expert in my field, and (2) a new professor (I was one of the first two students they supervised)

Things were progressing well, but I ended up working on a currently unsolvable problem (but I was still encouraged to work on it), so I spent 3-4 months and ended up hitting a dead end. So I changed directions a little bit. Then Covid hit, and it was pretty hard on me in the very heavy parts of my research. I got by well during Covid, but I had a bit of a mental snap in April when my city went into its third hard lockdown.

I also have a co-supervisor, and I really respected the co-supervisor because they were very knowledgeable in an adjacent topic related to what I was studying. However, there were several times I wanted to seek help from my co-supervisor, but my main supervisor advised me against it. Occasionally though, I met with the co-supervisor under the radar to try and seek guidance, but without undermining my primary supervisor. Fast forward to today, and now my co-supervisor is getting involved because I was presenting what my main supervisor deemed as “finished” work. My co-supervisor was supposed to just review the writing and then I would defend in April...

As it turns out, all of the stuff I wanted to speak to my co-supervisor about were pointed out as being very wrong (of course). Add in a miscommunication about how my funding was to be structured, and I’m now approaching year 3 and have had no income or financial support for about two months.

I’m beaten down, burnt out, have no financial support, and no more will to keep going. Things would be different if I wasn't in such a bad financial situation, but there is just no longer any funding and this degree is becoming more of a benefit than a drain. I really feel like my main supervisor has some responsibility for how my research has turned out, but I’m trying not to make them the entire focus of blame; sometimes things just do not work out.

However, I discovered that I really loved programming and want to get into some type of software development. So I was considering withdrawing from this current program in September and applying for a technical 2 year degree that would get me ready to program in the private sector. So there’s some good light from this experience at least because I know what I would do as a follow up.

**TL;DR**

I haven’t had less than a 60 hour work week for two and a half years at less than minimum wage, and I’m as burnt out as one can be. The result is that I may drop my masters program on the third year anniversary. But if I made a career switch to an entirely different area, how bad would it look on my resume if I dropped nearing year 3, and what would be a good way to address this if it comes up?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Basically, I just went into a very deep depression. I have never been depressed in my life, so this was very new for me. I've recovered from it, but it was the constant going in and out of lockdowns that really took a heavy toll. I use strength training as my main outlet for years, so having that taken away from me was very hard with respect to managing stress. And to your second point, I would work for a year and then likely get back into it so I have some financial security.

Comment: What country are you in?  Since you're in a master's program, I assume you got a bachelor's degree already (or your country's equivalent).  In the US, it would be pretty odd to get a lower degree (I assume the "technical 2 year degree" would be an associate's degree) after a higher one and there are plenty of employers that will be happy to hire someone with a BA/BS in a technical field that has been doing some amount of programming for several years without needing a CS degree.

Comment: @JustinCave I am located in Canada. I did my undergraduate in economics, so I haven't had much of an opportunity to write code, since I just picked up Python during my graduate degree. The 2 year technical program has some benefits, but primarily just having time to focus on building projects for my GitHub and networking in my city is where I see value in doing it. I am still just trying to weigh the pros and cons of it still.

Comment: Also see: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58218097#58218097 (sorry for the harsh yellow)

Comment: But you've been in grad school for 3 years so I assume you've had time to pick up plenty of programming knowledge to be able to get an entry level job so you've got money coming in rather than spending 2 more years in school not making money.  And you can probably network more effectively when you're employed too.

Comment: @JustinCave Yeah I have some programming knowledge, just nothing that is ready for a GitHub. I am going to be applying to some positions, but I'll likely need to pick up SQL to start being hirable (it seems to be in demand with Python where I am from). Don't get me wrong, if I can find an entry level programming job I would most certainly take that over more schooling; the issue I am concerned about is withdrawing from my masters and how that would appear.

Answer (score 3):

Dropping the Masters - no one will care per se.  Having been in university for the last 9-10 years, however, will be concerning and you will want to make sure to do some internships as you proceed with the tech courses so that you have some real work experience to show when you get out and are looking for full time employment.  “I’m pushing 30 and looking for my first job” can worry people about your focus.

Comment: Yeah I certainly would not be entering that program just thinking courses are enough. Even on that note, I may just find work experience and work on building a portfolio on the side. I’ve sleuthed around forums enough to become aware that work experience and projects are really the king in the tech space.

Comment: I'm really surprised how little master's thesis is valued, because it's basically proof that one can sit down and do boring and difficult stuff to completion, i.e. work.

Answer (score -1):

> But if I made a career switch to an entirely different area, how bad would it look on my resume if I dropped nearing year 3,

It doesn't look particularly good. You started a Master's program (as many other people do) and you didn't finish it (while most people do), so that's a bit of a ding. If you are planning on dropping it, drop it as soon as possible. Everyone can end up in a bad situation, so it matters how you deal with it. Considered and decisive action is better than shooting from the hip or letting it drag forever.

> and what would be a good way to address this if it comes up?

It's going to come up all right. The most tricky part will be the resume scanning phase where someone will take one or two minutes to scan through your resume and than either put it on the "good" or "bad" pile. You need to address it as good as you can on the resume itself.

Sorry, that's a tough situation to be in. A few things to consider.

1. How sure are you that you want to be SW developer? It's most efficient if you can set a clear goal and work towards it. Is that you career goal?
2. You started the Master's for a reason. Is that reason still valid or have your priorities shifted?
3. Would the Master's be relevant to your current career goals or not?
4. What can you negotiate with your supervisor/university? They clearly owe you one: if a capable student ends up in a situation like this, some supervision mistakes have been made. Maybe there is a short cut to get you over the finish line quickly. Talk to potential other supervisors, the dean, faculty staff, other students. This doesn't look good on the track record of your supervisor or the faculty either and most master thesis' are never read again after they have been submitted so there is a fair bit of wiggle room.
5. What are your potential options of getting into SW development? This field is less concerned with formal degrees than most others. Maybe you can do some interning or light-weight freelance work while you take some online classes in parallel. Hands on work maybe more valuable (and more fun and more lucrative) than another two years in school.

Comment: Nobody will actually care.  There's plenty of reasons to drop a masters.  I've worked with many people who dropped out of them or out of PHDs.  It will pretty much be ignored, unless they're going for researcher type roles.  Then it may matter.